# ¿Cómo ocurre el procesamiento de plantillas en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una duda, cuando en una plantilla se ejecuta algo como:

```
@foreach ($articulos as $articulo)
//html
{{$articulo->id}}<br>
{{$articulo->name}}<br>
{{$articulo->value}}<br>
@endforeach
```

que hace internamente laravel ... que archivos invoca exactamente ... metodos;
existe alguna manera de ver en pantalla un print con el tracking de ejecución (no Xdebug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blade es el sistema de plantillas de Laravel. Este sistema tiene caracteristicas que nos permiten trabajar más fácilmente con nuestro código HTML y PHP.

Cuando se realiza una plantilla o un archivo `.blade.php` Laravel compila y guarda en caché las vistas generadas en formato `.php`, estas vistas pueden ser vistas en `/storage/framework/views`. Esto te ahorra todo el trabajo de escribir código PHP nativo simplificándolo a directivas más sencillas.

En un pequeño ejemplo, algo como tu ejemplo:

```
@foreach ($articulos as $articulo)
//html
{{$articulo->id}}<br>
{{$articulo->name}}<br>
{{$articulo->value}}<br>
@endforeach
```

En el archivo compilado se podrá observar algo como:

```
<?php $__currentLoopData = $articulos; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $articulo): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
<?php echo e($articulo->id); ?><br>
<?php echo e($articulo->name); ?><br>
<?php echo e($articulo->value); ?><br>
<?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
```

Así como otras líneas de código correspondientes a las librerias y la localización de tu proyecto. Te dejo [aquí](https://styde.net/blade-el-sistema-de-plantillas-de-laravel/) más información al respecto. Saludos.

Comment: entonces en pocas palabras `arculutos.blade.php` es un archivo de pseudo plantillas  **intermediario** de directivas para generar el archivo vista con php nativo??? me imagino que el sistema de directivas de laravel y blade es muy complejo como para extraerlo y exportarlo fuera de laravel.... he intentarlo usar en un proyecto con php nativo???

Comment: que pasa en el caso que se imprima algo con `{{}}` y la pagina sea multi-idioma blade tiene la capacidad de trabajar con diccionario???